# Including refresh token in tmp folder using Google App Engine problem

Tags: python, flask, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I lanunched a flask app on Google App Engine that uses google sheets API. I am having problem with acessing my refresh token located in tmp directory.

auth code looks like this:

```
def access_sheet():
    creds = None
    if os.path.exists('tmp/token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('tmp/token.json', SCOPES)
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'tmp/credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        with open('tmp/token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    try:
        service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
        sheet = service.spreadsheets()
        return sheet

    except HttpError as err:
        print(err)
```

Altough I put credentials.json and token.json inside tmp directory, I still keep getting
**OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'tmp/token.json' **

I'd really like to avoid cloud storage, just because the only files I need to store are just these two.

How to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: start the path with `/` to use the `/tmp` located at the root level.

Comment: Your code is trying to write to `<CurrentWorkingDirectory>/tmp/token.json`. That is a read-only file system. Use the absolute path `/tmp/token.json`.

Comment: It works, thanks!!

I just wonder why was it necessary to add ''/'' to path, as I was running script from main.py file, located in root directory.

Comment: Your code is not running in the root directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said above, you have to use

```
/tmp/token.json
```

instead of

```
tmp/token.json
```